# C# Regex Range in Reverse order

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have got list of ASCII Codes of character which are allowed in the name.So, I am trying to build regex patter using range(-) hypen operator and string length should be 40.

Finally, I have ended up by creating following pattern.

```
^([\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x2E\x30-\x3B\x3F-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]){0,40}$
```

with this pattern I am specifying the range of character's ASCII codes allowed in the string.

But it throws exception of Range in reverse order. I have gone through couple of question. I have found that it happens because of hypen(-) character. So, In order to remove this problem I have to use escape sequence (-) instead of(-).

**After adding escape sequence although it doesn't throw exception but it doesn't give the desire result.**

So, I want to know is my pattern is correct or Is it right away to specify ASCII Code character range.

Comment: `\x3F-7E` -> [`\x3F-\x7E`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5b%5cx20-%5cx21%5cx23-%5cx25%5cx28-%5cx2E%5cx30-%5cx3B%5cx3F-%5cx7E%5cxA0-%5cxFF%5d)%7b0%2c40%7d%24&i=++some+text+here+). Just a typo, right?

Comment: Yes it was typo, but If I correct it. Still it doesn't give desired result

Comment: What is the desired result? String must be *exactly* 40 symbols long? Remove `0,`. And remove `(` and `)`, no need  grouping 1 symbol.

Comment: \x19 is not valid character so, it should not match. Regex.IsMatch() should return false

Comment: [It does not match](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5b%5cx20-%5cx21%5cx23-%5cx25%5cx28-%5cx2E%5cx30-%5cx3B%5cx3F-%5cx7E%5cxA0-%5cxFF%5d)%7b0%2c40%7d%24&i=++some+text+%19here+) (note the `\x19` before `here`).

Comment: I am very new to regex expression. All I want if any character except form above specified list ascii codes is found in the string, then I need to throw validation message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95423/discussion-between-yogesh-joshi-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), remove the grouping, quantifier, anchors and fix the typo:

```
[^\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x2E\x30-\x3B\x3F-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5Cx20-%5Cx21%5Cx23-%5Cx25%5Cx28-%5Cx2E%5Cx30-%5Cx3B%5Cx3F-%5Cx7E%5CxA0-%5CxFF%5D&i=%20%20some%20text%20%19here%20) (1 match is found before `here`) and use it as shown in the below [C# demo](http://ideone.com/dr8swK):

```
var str = "  some text here ";
if (str.Length > 40 || Regex.IsMatch(str, @"[^\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x2E\x30-\x3B\x3F-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]"))
    Console.WriteLine("The line is too long or contains invalid char(s)!");
```

Note that a negated character class is formed with the help of `[^....]` notation and matches all characters other than those specified in the character class.

If performance is key, you need to declare the regex as a static readonly field with `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag. Have a look at the [Kurt Schindler's *Regular expression performance comparisons* blog](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/regular-expression-performance-comparisons/).

Comment: Ya it works fine but I had to add check  length of string should be between lower limit 0 and upper limit 40. So, I had to add {0,40}$ in the end of expression

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? Just check the string length. It is possible to do with regex , but why should you sacrifice performance? Add `str.Length > 40 ||`.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that it would have performance hit but in my case I would be using the same expression so many places. So, Instead of using extra code, I wan to do with the help of regex. I have read that {0,40}$ it should work perfectly fine for me but with the conjuction of above pattern it is not working. Moreover, its going to be very small string. So, no risk of performance hits

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/dr8swK) showing that `@"^[\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x2E\x30-\x3B\x3F-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]{0,40}$"` should be working for you.

Comment: I have found out that already in-fact  this is the same what I had started

Comment: So, the only issue was the typo.